# how check for member operator(type)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

Suppose I have types `bar` and `foo`. How can I construct a template class `has_call_with_arg<>` such that `has_call_with_arg<bar,foo>::value` is true if and only if

```
bar b;
foo f;
b(f);
```

would compile? I looked into various related questions (*including that mentioned above*) and tried

```
template<typename Func, typename Arg>
class has_call_with_arg
{
  struct bad {};
  struct test : Func
  {
    template<typename C>
    bad operator()(C const&r);
  };
public:
  static const bool value = 
    !std::is_same<bad, typename std::result_of<test(Arg const&)>::type >::value;
};
```

but that didn't work (didn't detect a correct match). What's wrong?

Comment: +1 just because of the silly puppy.

Comment: Not really a dupe- named member functions and member operators are generally a different deal.

Comment: See specifically my answer in the linked dupe.

Comment: because `bad operator()(C const&r)` hides any other `operator()` that `Func` might have had.

Comment: @Xeo it was not obvious to me that/how your answer can be used here. There is quite a difference between named member functions and member operators, particularly with operator(), which cannot be made a non-member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename sig, typename functor> struct is_callable;
template<typename Ret, typename... Arg, typename functor> 
struct is_callable<Ret(Arg...), functor> { // partial spec
private:
    struct no {};
public:
    template<typename U> static auto f(std::nullptr_t) -> decltype(std::declval<U>()(std::declval<Arg>()...));
    template<typename U> static no f(...);
    static const int value = std::is_convertible<decltype(f<functor>(nullptr)), Ret>::value;
};
```

I created this content [for my tutorials](http://codepuppy.co.uk/cpptuts/TMP/SFINAE.aspx), which explain the construction of this trait (non-variadic form first).

Comment: Nice. I have a follow up question: Do we really need the first overload of `f` to have a trailling return type? In a simple test case that I've tried it worked with a standard (i.e. no trailling) return type. I wonder if there's a trap somewhere that the trailling return type avoids.

Answer (score 2):

`std::result_of<test(Arg const&)>` supplies a template parameter which is the function type taking a reference to `Arg const` and returning a `test`.  So its `type` is `test`, not too helpful.

Note that as written, requiring the code

```
bar b;
foo f;
b(f);
```

to be valid is really 5 requirements:  `bar` and `foo` each have an accessible default constructor and destructor, and `b(f)` is a valid expression.  I'm going to focus on just the last one (which is maybe all you meant).  If you really did mean the other parts, those can be added in using standard `<type_traits>` properties.

The function `std::declval` is perfect for pretending you have an object of a given type, even when you don't.  It must never be called, so it's usually used just within a `decltype` expression.

There are two basic ways to pull off an SFINAE trick, based on two places C++ allows template argument deduction failure to just discard the failed declaration:

First, trying to match a class partial specialization:

```
template<typename Func, typename Arg, typename Enable = void>
struct has_call_with_arg1 : public std::false_type {};

template<typename Func, typename Arg>
struct has_call_with_arg1<Func, Arg,
    decltype(std::declval<Func&>()(std::declval<Arg&>()))>
    : public std::true_type {};
```

Second, overload resolution when at least one of the overloads is a function template.  (A non-template member function of a class template won't work here, because instantiating the class requires each member declaration to be valid.)

```
namespace has_call_with_arg_impl {
    template<typename F, typename A>
    std::true_type test(decltype(std::declval<F&>()(std::declval<A&>()))*);

    template<typename F, typename A>
    std::false_type test(...);
}

template <typename Func, typename Arg>
struct has_call_with_arg2
    : public decltype(has_call_with_arg_impl::test<Func,Arg>(nullptr)) {};
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/KgRI8y

Comment: The second implementation seems correct to me but the first one doesn't work if the type returned by the callable type isn't `void`. For instance, for `struct F { int operator()(double) { return 0; } };` we have `has_call_with_arg1<F, double>::value == false`. Indeed, `has_call_with_arg1` takes 3 arguments but the 3rd one, `Enable`, has a default `= void`. When providing only 2 arguments, the 3rd one gets the default and the primary template is selected. However, `has_call_with_arg1<F, double, int>::value == true` because the specialization is a better match than the primary.

Comment: Good catch.  Maybe that's why I usually go the function way.  But I thought there was some useful trick involving a default template argument `typename Enable=void`....